# What's the complexity of this (non-preemptive) scheduling algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, scheduling

I have a question about the algorithmic complexity of a job (non-preemptive) scheduling algorithm, used in particular to obtain the optimal solution to a 1||sum(Uj) problem (one machine only), where Uj is a unitary penalty (that is: equal to 0 if the job terminates by its deadline, and equal to 1 if it terminates late).

I need to minimize the sum of unitary penalties (that is: the sum of late jobs). The job processing times are given, together with their deadlines and there's no release time (so, all the jobs are released synchronously at time t=0).
The algoritm works like this:

*1- sequence all the jobs according to Earliest Due Date*

*2- identify the first late job Jj. If there are no late jobs go to step 4.*

*3- identify the largest processing time job between Jj and its predecessors. Remove that job and return to step 2, considering the new sequence without the removed job*

*4- The optimal sequence is given by: current sequence [followed by] subset of jobs removed at step 3 in any order.*

I'm asked to compute the worst case O(...) complexity of this algorithm, in a general and good implemented case (so, I have to try to guess the complexity "implementation-free" for the moment, given all the algorithm steps).

I think that step 1 requires O(nlogn) since (using QuickSort or MergeSort) it's just a matter of ordering.

But then, what about steps 2-3-4? Is it correct to state that the final complexity may be O(n^2) if we try to implement this for example in C/C++? Or is it O(n*logn) thanks to EDD "optimizing" the subsequent search? What could be a possible proof to determine its complexity?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that this whole algorithm can be done in `O(n log n)` time. The basic idea is to amortize the cost of removing predecessors. Each time we remove a predecessor, we will pay `O(log n)`, and there will be at most `n` removals.

Here's the specifics. After step 1, you only need to do a single pass over the jobs, since deleting jobs from the sequence can only make jobs finish sooner. Every time you consider a job in the sequence, you repeatedly remove its largest predecessor until it finishes on time. Notice that the **total number** of "remove the largest predecessor" operations is at most `n`, since each job will be removed at most once. [Note: I believe some care is needed here because "predecessor" should be an inclusive notion. That is, when considering a particular job j, if j is larger than any previous job, then you should remove j and move on to the next job.]

How do you implement the "remove the largest predecessor" operation efficiently? You can do this by maintaining (as you walk through the jobs left-to-right) an ordering on predecessors *by job size*. This ordering can be implemented with, for example, a binary search tree, which permits insertions and deletions in `O(log n)`. Every time you begin considering a job, you insert it into the tree, paying `O(log n)`. Deleting the largest predecessor is simply just deleting the largest job from the tree.

Earlier we noticed that there will be at most `n` removals, corresponding to at most `n` deletions from the tree. Thus we pay a total cost of `O(n log n)` for deletions. We also pay a total cost of `O(n log n)` for insertions (exactly one insertion per job). The preprocessing step of sorting all the data is `O(n log n)`, so the total cost of all steps is `O(n log n)`.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
J = input sorted by earliest due date
T = empty tree
for each j in J, from left to right:
  insert j into T
  while j does not finish on time:
    j' = delete largest from T
    if j' == j:
      break to next job in J
```

The only detail I've left out is how to check if a job finishes on time. But that is pretty straightforward, since you can keep track of the "current finishing time" simply by adding and subtracting from a counter as jobs are inserted and deleted from the tree.